# electric depositing on rocket engine

Tags: rockets

I saw a video from *Everyday Astronaut* in which he mentioned electric depositing on a rocket engine. How can thin depositing stand for high pressures?

> 

Answer (score 4):

Electrolytic deposition of metals is slow. With a current of 1 ampere, only 329 microgram of copper are deposited in one second. In one hour this current transfers 1.185 gram and in one day of 24 hours 28.44 gram. (valence of copper: 2)

A current density of 5 A/dm^2 delivers about 1 µm per minute, that is 60 µm/h or 1.44 mm per day.

Using high current densities for some days, a layer of some mm may be deposited. So layers suitable for high pressure are possible.

1000 A is needed for an area of 2 square meters and a current density of 5 A/dm^2.